# iteration not working when accessing files in Firebase, but working when files are on the phone

Tags: firebase, flutter, iteration

I have created two widgets. One is working very well. For the second one, I am using the same code, but in that case, the files are on FireBase.
Strangely, the iteration does not work. With the code, it will be easier to understand.

```
 List<Widget> getList() {
    List<Widget> childs = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < filesReference.length; i++) {
      String  extensionFile = filesReference[i].toString().split('.').last;

      childs.add(
          GestureDetector(
            onTap: (){
              //if document PDF display content of the file
              if (extensionFile == 'pdf') {
                Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (context) =>
                            Display_PDF_Selected(selectedPdfPath: filesReference[i].toString(), pdfIndex: i)));
              } else if (extensionFile =='jpeg'){
                Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (context) =>
                            Display_Image_Selected(
                              pathSelectedImage: filesReference[i].toString(),
                              imageIndex: i ,
                            )));
              }
              else if(extensionFile =='jpg'){
                Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (context) =>
                            Display_Image_Selected(
                              pathSelectedImage: filesReference[i].toString(),
                              imageIndex: i ,
                            )));
              }
              else if(extensionFile =='png'){
                  Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (context) =>
                  Display_Image_Selected(
                  pathSelectedImage: filesReference[i].toString(),
                  imageIndex: i ,
                  )));
              };
            },
            child: Card(
              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
              ),
              elevation: 10,
              child: ClipPath(
                clipper: ShapeBorderClipper(
                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15))),
                child: Row(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    Container(
                      height: 113,width: 113,
                      child: extensionFile == 'pdf'?
                      Image.asset('assets/images/logo_pdf.png',
                        // fit: BoxFit.fill,
                        //  width: double.infinity,
                      ):

                      Image.file(File(filesReference[i].toString()),
                        fit: BoxFit.fill,
                        width: double.infinity,),
                    ),
                    Expanded(
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                        child: Text(filesReference[i].toString().split('/').last,//_nameOfFile,//name,
                          style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right:25.0),
                      child: IconButton(onPressed: (){
                        //delete a record and the card displaying this record
                        // Delete the selected image

                        setState(() {
                          if (filesReference.length !=0) {
                            filesReference.removeAt(i);
                          };
                        });
                      },
                        icon:Icon (Icons.delete, color: Colors.red,),),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              //subtitle: Text(path),
            ),
          ));}
    return childs;
  }
```

On the second one below, the print display the right information for task_Attachments.length = 3,

But the iteration stay at 0. It is like if 'j' is not incrementing. I do not understand why. Thank you

```
List<Widget> getListFromFireBaseV2(){
    List<Widget> filesFromFireBase=[];
    print(task_Attachments.length);
    for (int j=0;j<task_Attachments.length;j++ ){
print(j);

      filesFromFireBase.add(
        
            Card(
              child:
                  Row(
                    children: [
                     // Container(
                      //    height: 40,
                      //    child: Image.network(task_Attachments[nbFile].toString())),
                      Expanded(
                        child: Text(task_Attachments[j].toString())
                     ),
                    ],
                  ),
              ),

      );
      return filesFromFireBase;
    }
  }
``
```

Comment: I think you are returning your widget array in the first iteration of the for loop and not allowing it to  continue. Just move return filesFromFireBase; below the } under it.

Comment: Many thanks. I feel stupid. This was under my nose and I did not see it. Again, many thanks. Now it works fine :-)